# photos splitting into primary colours when uploading to instagram reels

Tags: lightroom, fujifilm, instagram

I process RAW files taken with my fuji xt-1 and after editing them in lightroom classic, I export them to smaller file jpegs and put them up on my insta account. Recently thought I would try out reels too. Put up a montage with a song.

My first went fine, which I used some film photos(converted from BMP to jpegs on photoshop).
My second attempt was with photos I edited as per the process mentioned above. Instead of uploading properly, the issue I have been facing is:

-during the final preview, the images are splitting into colours
-the final upload is just black

This is not something that happens if I used photos or videos taken with my phone, or any images downloaded from the internet, or screenshots.  It does not happen to images from my library if I go back a year or two. Just for some.

I have attached screenshots of the what errors look like.  I am flummoxed by this weirdly specific error. Would appreciate any input. [black screenshot of what reels actually uploads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iytAn.jpg)

[image: tonal split of photo visible in preview section]

Comment: You should provide a demo jpg file and share details on how you exported them (JPEG settings). Have you tried re-exporting and re-uploading the files that caused the issue?

Comment: Also do you use any Instagram filter? Have you try to export PNG and upload it?